# AngularJS - Scope Not Updating

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

For some reason, I can't remove the description and packing elements/fields (see picture) from the scope variable, even after deleting their respective code and restarting the application. Any help is much appreciated.

[image: Form screenshot]

My directive:

```
app.directive('formElement', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
        label : "@",
        model : "="
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.disabled = attrs.hasOwnProperty('disabled');
        scope.required = attrs.hasOwnProperty('required');
        scope.pattern = attrs.pattern || '.*';
        console.log(element);
    },
    template:
    '<div class="form-group">' +
    '<label class="col-sm-3 control-label no-padding-right"> {{label}}</label>' +
    '<div class="col-sm-7">' +
    '<span class="block input-icon input-icon-right" ng-transclude></span>' +
    '</div></div>'
  };     
});
```

My controllers:

```
 app.controller('ProductsCtrl', function ($scope, $modal, $filter, Data) {
        $scope.product = {};
        Data.get('products').then(function(data){
            $scope.products = data.data;
        });
        $scope.changeProductStatus = function(product){
            product.status = (product.status=="Active" ? "Inactive" : "Active");
            Data.put("products/"+product.id,{status:product.status});
        };
        $scope.deleteProduct = function(product){
            if(confirm("Are you sure to remove the product?")){
                Data.delete("products/"+product.id).then(function(result){
                    $scope.products = _.without($scope.products, _.findWhere($scope.products, {id:product.id}));
                });
            }
        };
        $scope.open = function (p,size) {
            var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                templateUrl: 'partials/product-edit.html',
                controller: 'ProductEditCtrl',
                size: size,
                resolve: {
                    item: function () {
                        return p;
                    }
                }
            });
            modalInstance.result.then(function(selectedObject) {
                if(selectedObject.save == "insert"){
                    $scope.products.push(selectedObject);
                    $scope.products = $filter('orderBy')($scope.products, 'id', 'reverse');
                }else if(selectedObject.save == "update"){
                    p.price = selectedObject.price;
                    p.stock = selectedObject.stock;
                }
            });
        };

        $scope.columns = [
            {text:"ID",predicate:"id",sortable:true,dataType:"number"},
            {text:"Name",predicate:"name",sortable:true},
            {text:"Price",predicate:"price",sortable:true},
            {text:"Stock",predicate:"stock",sortable:true},
            {text:"Status",predicate:"status",sortable:true},
            {text:"Action",predicate:"",sortable:false}
        ];
    });

    app.controller('ProductEditCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance, item, Data) {

        $scope.product = angular.copy(item);

        $scope.cancel = function () {
            $modalInstance.dismiss('Close');
        };
        $scope.title = (item.id > 0) ? 'Edit Product' : 'Add Product';
        $scope.buttonText = (item.id > 0) ? 'Update Product' : 'Add New Product';

        var original = item;
        $scope.isClean = function() {
            return angular.equals(original, $scope.product);
        };

        $scope.saveProduct = function (product) {
            product.uid = $scope.uid;
            if(product.id > 0){
                Data.put('products/'+product.id, product).then(function (result) {
                    if(result.status != 'error'){
                        var x = angular.copy(product);
                        x.save = 'update';
                        $modalInstance.close(x);
                    }else{
                        console.log(result);
                    }
                });
            }else{
                product.status = 'Active';
                Data.post('products', product).then(function (result) {
                    if(result.status != 'error'){
                        var x = angular.copy(product);
                        x.save = 'insert';
                        x.id = result.data;
                        $modalInstance.close(x);
                    }else{
                        console.log(result);
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

HTML:

product-edit.html (partial):

```
<div class="modal-header">
      <h3 class="modal-title">Edit product [ID: {{product.id}}]</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <form name="product_form" class="form-horizontal" role="form" novalidate>

        <form-element label="NAME" mod="product">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Name" ng-model="product.name" ng-disabled="product.id" focus/>
        </form-element>

        <form-element label="PRICE" mod="product">
            <input type="text" name="price" class="form-control" placeholder="PRICE" ng-model="product.price"  only-numbers/>
            <small class="errorMessage" ng-show="product_form.price.$dirty && product_form.price.$invalid"> Enter the price.</small>
        </form-element>

       <form-element label="STOCK" mod="product">
            <input type="text" name="stock" class="form-control" placeholder="STOCK" ng-model="product.stock" only-numbers/>
            <small class="errorMessage" ng-show="product_form.stock.$dirty && product_form.stock.$invalid"> Enter the available stock.</small>
        </form-element>


        <div class="modal-footer">
            <form-element label="">
                <div class="text-right">
                    <a class="btn btn-sm" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</a>
                    <button ng-click="saveProduct(product);"
                            ng-disabled="product_form.$invalid || enableUpdate"
                            class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"
                            type="submit">
                        <i class="ace-icon fa fa-check"></i>{{buttonText}}
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form-element>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

products.html (partial):

```
<div class="panel panel-default">

    <div class="panel-heading" style="height: 60px;">


        <div class="pull-left">
            <input placeholder="Filter inventory list ..." class="form-control" aria-describedby="basei" ng-model="filterProduct" ng-change="resetLimit();"  autocomplete="off" type="text" focus>
        </div>

        <div class="pull-right">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default fa fa-plus" ng-click="open(product);">Add New Product</button>
        </div>


    </div>

    <div class="panel-body">

        <div class="input-group pull-right">
        </div>

        <table class="table table-striped">

            <tr ng-show="products.length==0"><td style="vertical-align:middle;"><i class="fa fa-ban fa-3x"></i>&nbsp;No data found</td></tr>

            <tr ng-hide="products.length>-1"><td style="vertical-align:middle;"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>&nbsp;Loading</td></tr>

            <tr><th ng-repeat="c in columns">{{c.text}}</th></tr>

            <tr ng-repeat="c in products | filter:filterProduct | orderBy:'-id'" id="{{c.id}}" animate-on-change='c.stock + c.price' ng-animate=" 'animate'">

                <td>{{c.id}}</td><td>{{c.name}}</td><td>{{c.price}}</td><td>{{c.stock}}</td>

                <td>

                    <button class="btn" ng-class="{Active:'btn-success', Inactive:''}[c.status]" ng-click="changeProductStatus(c);">{{c.status}}</button>

                </td>

                <td>

                    <div class="btn-group">

                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default fa fa-edit" ng-click="open(c);"></button>

                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger fa fa-trash-o" ng-click="deleteProduct(c);"></button>

                    </div>

                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Is there an HTML (like index.html) connected to this with some content perhaps?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Added...

Comment: Can you put a plunker example? Or at least put the file names next to the code you posted? It may be as simple as you trying to edit the wrong file name.

Comment: Your question states that you are having problems with scope, but the body of the question seems to indicate that the problem is with cached HTML, and not with scope at all.

Answer (score 1):

I often have a problem with my templates being cached while using Angular. In chrome if you have the developer console open you can go to settings and prevent it from using cached results while the console is open. Or clear your browser cache manually